# How to open browser preview from intellij in flatpak google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, intellij-idea, flatpak

When I try to open browser preview in Google Chrome, I encounter this error:

[image: browser error]

Unfortunately, I have installed Google Chrome via [flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.google.Chrome), and there is no working installation path that I can just provide to IntelliJ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two options.

#### If Chrome *is* your default browser

You can use whatever "open" command you have for URLs. In my case it's `xdg-open`:

[image]

#### If Chrome *is not* your default browser

You need to start it via flatpak.

First, type `flatpak` in "Path":

[image]

Then click on edit button and paste `run --command=/app/bin/chrome com.google.Chrome` in
"Command line options":

[image]

This works as I expect it to, opening new tab in existing Chrome window.

---

My IntelliJ is not sandboxed, it's managed by [JetBrains Toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/toolbox/) which in turn was semi-manually installed with this [script](https://gist.github.com/greeflas/431bc50c23532eee8a7d6c1d603f3921).

Naturally, I have `flatpak` on PATH.